# how to get urls from google query?

Tags: python, html, url, google-search

hi guys i've try to urls from google but it's return 0 urls !

this is my code what the wrong with it ?

```
    import string, sys, time, urllib2, cookielib, re, random, threading, socket, os, time
def Search(go_inurl,maxc):
    header = ['Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; SunOS 5.10 sun4u; X11)',
          'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2pre) Gecko/20100207 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Namoroka/3.6.2pre',
          'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Avant Browser;',
      'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0)',
      'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 5.1)',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6)',
      'Microsoft Internet Explorer/4.0b1 (Windows 95)',
      'Opera/8.00 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)',
      'amaya/9.51 libwww/5.4.0',
      'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; AOL 4.0; Windows 95; c_athome)',
      'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)',
      'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.5; Linux) KHTML/3.5.5 (like Gecko) (Kubuntu)',
      'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; ZoomSpider.net bot; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)',
      'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; QihooBot 1.0 qihoobot@qihoo.net)',
      'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows ME) Opera 5.11 [en]']
    gnum=100
    uRLS = []
    counter = 0
        while counter < int(maxc):
                jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies")
                query = 'q='+go_inurl
                results_web = 'http://www.google.com/cse?'+'cx=011507635586417398641%3Aighy9va8vxw&ie=UTF-8&'+'&'+query+'&num='+str(gnum)+'&hl=en&lr=&ie=UTF-8&start=' + repr(counter) + '&sa=N'
                request_web = urllib2.Request(results_web)
        agent = random.choice(header)
                request_web.add_header('User-Agent', agent)
        opener_web = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
                text = opener_web.open(request_web).read()
        strreg = re.compile('(?<=href=")(.*?)(?=")')
                names = strreg.findall(text)
        counter += 100
                for name in names:
                        if name not in uRLS:
                                if re.search(r'\(', name) or re.search("<", name) or re.search("\A/", name) or re.search("\A(http://)\d", name):
                                        pass
                elif re.search("google", name) or re.search("youtube", name) or re.search(".gov", name) or re.search("%", name):
                                        pass
                else:
                                        uRLS.append(name)
    tmpList = []; finalList = []
        for entry in uRLS:
        try:
            t2host = entry.split("/",3)
            domain = t2host[2]
            if domain not in tmpList and "=" in entry:
                finalList.append(entry)
                tmpList.append(domain)
        except:
            pass
    print "[+] URLS (sorted)   :", len(finalList)
    return finalList
```

also i've done a lot of editing and still nothing happen ! please show me what is my mistake .. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It appears to be completely random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues I see with this. Firstly, you are using a custom Google search that (apparently) seems to return only results from google.com. This combined with a regex that looks for the occurrence of "google" in the url (`re.search("google", name)`), and when found does *not* add it to the list of urls will cause the list of urls to always remain empty for this custom search.

Additionally and more importantly, your logic is incorrect. With fixed formatting, you currently do this:

```
if name not in uRLS:
    if re.search(r'\(', name) or re.search("<", name) or re.search("\A/", name) or re.search("\A(http://)\d", name):
        pass
    elif re.search("google", name) or re.search("youtube", name) or re.search(".gov", name) or re.search("%", name):
        pass
    else:
        uRLS.append(name)
```

(Note that the `elif` and `else` might be indented once to much, but still, the problem will persist.)

Because you check if `name` is not in `uRLS`, `name` will never get added to that list because the adding logic is in your `else` path.

To fix it, remove the `else`, decrease the indentation of the `append` statement, and replace the `pass` statements with `continue`.

Comment: 1. As you custom search only returns url's with "google" in them, the `re.search("google", name)` check always returns `True`: remove this function call. --- 2. Remove the line with `else` from the snippet I posted, and remove four spaces in front of the `uRLS.append(name)` line.

Answer (score 0):

jro is right, moreover Google periodically changes the format of their results, not monthly but yes more than one time per year, then your regular expression could fail and you need to modify it.

I face similar issues than you in the past and I opt for an easy solution, these guys provide a **[google scraper to extract all URLs from search results](http://goohackle.com/)** that works great, you provide the keywords and they scrape and parse the Google results and returns you the links, anchors, descriptions, etc. It's a different approach for a solution but it could help you as well.